# Return a variable to a view

Tags: php, laravel, variables

I have a question about Laravel.

I have by example index.blade.php. In this file I want include the sidebar who is located on the file sidebar.blade.php.

But now I want to send a variable from my controller(SidebarController) to the sidebar view: sidebar.blade.php.

Like this:

```
class SidebarController extends Controller
{
    public function news_widget() {

        $posts = Post::take(5)->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->take();
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following

```
class SidebarController extends Controller
{
    public function news_widget() {

        $posts = Post::take(5)->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->take();
        return view('index', array('data'=>$posts));
    }
}
```

And within index.blade.php include sidebar.blade.php

```
@include('sidebar',$data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class SidebarController extends Controller
{
    public function news_widget() {

        $posts = Post::take(5)->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->take();

       return View::make('sidebar')->with('posts', $posts);

    }
}
```